# Adapting the number of EditText inputs in Kotlin from user defined int value?

Tags: kotlin, android-textinputedittext

I am working on building an application in Android Studio and I have my Edittexts to accept user input (as int) and can pass it to the subsequent activity after clicking 'next'. However, my question is do I take this integer input and convert it to that number of subsequent inputs in the next activity? User inputs '5' for example and now I want in the next activity to be able for the user to define their 5 inputs. If 4, only create 4 new textEdits in the next activity etc.

I haven't seen a solution for this online and don't know how to create this variable input.

Answer (score 0):

Two different approaches.

1. If they are part of a big or complicated layout in a ScrollView, this is probably the one you should pick. Create a parent view for them, such as GridView or LinearLayout, in your XML layout for the Activity. You can add two or three EditTexts to this parent in your layout temporarily to figure out what layout params you want to give them to get the right look.

Then create another xml file to represent each individual EditText by itself, with the parameters it will have when added to the parent view. (You could alternatively skip this step and do all the EditText setup in Kotlin code, but that's a bit more complicated to get right.) This is just an example. You should use the layout parameters that make sense for what you're putting it in.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:inputType="text"/>
```

Then in `onCreate()`, you can instantiate them in a List constructor, and add them to the parent at the same time. Use the LayoutInflater to do this. The layout ID is the one for the XML file of the single EditText. PAssing `true` as the third parameter adds the newly inflated view to the parent view group.

```
val parentView = binding.editTextsParent // or findViewById if not using view binding

val editTexts = List(numberOfEditTexts) {
    layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_edit_text, parentView, true)
}
```

And now you have a List of your EditTexts that you can use to grab data from them, or iterate to set up TextWatchers, etc.

2. Use this if there are a lot of them or they are going to be the only thing on the screen. In this case, we would use a RecyclerView. There are tons of tutorials on RecyclerViews, so I won't explain exactly how it's done. But to apply a RecyclerView in this case, your backing list of data would be a List of Strings that is the same size as the number of EditTexts you want to create. The layout you create for each item to put in the RecyclerView.Adapter would have just an EditText in it. You would have to add a TextWatcher to each EditText that updates the values in the backing List as they are edited. This is so if an EditText is recycled (a new one scrolls onto the screen), you can update it with the text that the corresponding list item was last showing before it scrolled off the screen.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful! How would I incorporate a TextWatcher?